# Sul significato di "essere ritto su una macchina" (una persona)

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Le figlie della luna*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Seduta alle mie spalle sulla *capote* ribaltata della mia macchina c'era la ragazza nuda che indicava in direzione della Luna.
>
> Avrei voluto dirle che si mettesse giù, che non potevo attraversare la città con lei così in vista in quello stato, ma non osavo distrarla, tutta intenta com'era a non perdere di vista la macchia luminosa che ora spariva ora riappariva al fondo della Avenue. E poi, - quel che era più strano - nessun passante sembrava notare questa apparizione femminile ritta su una macchina scoperta.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ritto/) ho trovato quest'accezione dell'aggettivo "ritto":

> Di persona, dritto in piedi, in posizione eretta: *stava r. in mezzo alla stanza; si piantò r. davanti a lui; non restare lì r., mettiti a sedere; su, r.!*

Dopo leggerla ho subito pensato che il senso di "ritta" nel brano citato fosse che la ragazza era in piedi sulla macchina, ma quello che mi confonde è che previamente si dice che la ragazza era seduta sulla *capote*. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: che la ragazza era "ritta" sulla macchina significa necessariamente che era "in piedi"? O può semplicemente significare che era "in posizione verticale" (cioè, in questo contesto potrebbe significare che stava seduta, ma con la schiena molto  dritta)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A orecchio, propendo per la seconda ipotesi (che cioè la ragazza fosse seduta ma a torso dritto), anche perché se si sta seduti sulla *capote* abbassata – anziché in un sedile – si sporge di molto dalla sagoma dell'automobile, dando appunto l'idea di qualcosa in verticale sopra l'auto.

Comment: Sono d'accordo: l'auto era un'auto scoperta e probabilmente la ragazza era seduta sulla macchina ma in modo da risultare il più possibile "visibile", quindi probabilmente a busto diritto.

Answer (score 0):

Fra i sinonimi di [ritto](http://www.ilsinonimo.com/R/ritto/) c'è anche *impettito* che, a parer mio, è adeguato a questo contesto.